# Error when attempting to import VLC in Python

Tags: python, vlc

After running:

```
pip install vlc
```

I ran a python file containing:

```
from vlc import vlc
vlc.activate()
print vlc.active
```

The output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 1, in <module>
    from vlc import vlc
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/vlc/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from cls.application import application
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/vlc/cls/application.py", line 5, in <module>
    class application(application):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: Have you tried reporting the bug?

Comment: Did it install cleanly?

Comment: pip install vlc installed cleanly